# In MS Access, is it possible to add an updatable blank field to a query to calculate it's values programmatically in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, backend

In MS Access, in order to prevent nesting queries, because it has become really slow, I'm trying to calculate programmatically in VBA all calculated fields for my queries using a Loop. In general, the idea is to stop using calculated fields on queries at all, to perform all calculations from the backend.

I am having problems showing the values in a TextBox in a **Continuous Form**. I'm trying to create a query in VBA with an empty field and then update the field with the calculated values, so then I can set the ControlSource of the textbox to that field for it to show properly. The problem is that since the empty field is a calculated field, I cannot update it's value. Is there any other way to add a field to a query that remains empty and updatable until I can calculate it's values?

An alternative solution would be to create a temporal table instead of a query and update the values, but I would really prefer not to create temporal tables every time an user needs to do a query with calculated fields (especially nested ones).
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Here is what I tried:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim SQLQ As string
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim qrydef As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim i As Integer
    
    'calcField1 is not a member of Items, and it's intended to be updated later on
    SQLQ = "SELECT Items.Price, calcField1 FROM Items;"
    
    Set dbs = CurrentDb()    
    Set qrydef = dbs.CreateQueryDef("testqry", SQLQ)
    
    'Field is prompted for a value when the query is called and has no source
    qrydef!calcField1 = vbNullString        
    Set rs = qrydef.OpenRecordset()    
    
    i = 0
    Do Until rs.EOF
        rs.Edit
        rs!calcField1 = rs!Price *2 'Error here because calcField1 is a Calculated Field
        rs.Update
        i = i + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    Me.TextBox1.ControlSource = "=Price"
    Me.TextBox2.ControlSource = "=calcField1"
    Set Me.Recordset = rs
    
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: I hope I understood your problem correctly. I am not sure why you need to save a calculated field in a database back-end if it is needed to be displayed only. I mean in you example you could read only the price from back-end and make the calculation in the query body itself without saving to the back-end and in this case it will display Correctly in front end without slowing down or degrading performance.

Comment: You can use expression to second text to calculate value from first textbox easily. You can user functions, logics, comparisons to expression.

Comment: I simplified the question and the example here. The problem that I have is that nested queries get really slow, and I have a query that ran smoothly in 2 computers, but then I added some functionality with a nested query and it became really slow in one of the computers and smooth in the other one. I was told that doing the calculations on the backend is the way to go and I can't show the result properly in a continuous subform in access unless I use a recordset, and for that I wanted to have a query result to be edited, not just to create a new table every time I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to create another table where you can insert the new calculated record with a reference to the original table so they are linked.

for example:

table 1:
item_id, item_desc, price

table 2:
item_id, calculated_value

then, the calculated value can be inserted or modified depending on the purpose of your calculation process.

Comment: Yes, I considered that option, but I wanted to avoid it to prevent multiple users overflowing the database memory with multiple tables. If nothing else arises, this should be it.

Comment: Access doesn't handle concurrency very well. If you have multiple users inputting something at the same time, it could be a potential issue.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the calculated field into a query and use that as the Record Source?

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strSQL As string
    
    'calcField1 is calculated
    strSQL = "SELECT Items.Price, (Items.Price * 2) AS calcField1 FROM Items;"
    
    Me.TextBox1.ControlSource = "=Price"
    Me.TextBox2.ControlSource = "=calcField1"
    Set Me.RecordSource = SQLQ 
    
    Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

or if the logic is more complex you can put it into a function

```
'in the form
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim strSQL As string
    
    'calcField1 is computed by a function
    strSQL = "SELECT Items.Price, MyFunction(Items.Price) AS calcField1 FROM Items;"
    
    Me.TextBox1.ControlSource = "=Price"
    Me.TextBox2.ControlSource = "=calcField1"
    Set Me.RecordSource = strSQL 
    
    Me.Refresh
End Sub

'in a module
Public Function MyFunction(dbl As Double) As Double
    MyFunction = dbl * 2
End Function
```

Comment: Yes, that's the standard way, but that's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, since calculations inside queries are rather slow, and if they are nested queries it's annoyingly slow even for a small database. What I'm trying to accomplish is do the calculations in the backend using VBA.